# How to get difference between 2 images and save it to an image

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

And what i mean by the title is 
I have 2 images - each one is from a different time ( from screen cap)
i want to get the difference between the two 
make all the same parts transparent,
send the difference to a client
and place it on top of an image that he has

Don't worry about the sending part - I have covered that.
The thing I need help is how to get the difference, save it to an image / stream / byte array
and merging it to one image.

Comment: Compare the byte[] representation of the images?

Comment: yeah that culd work but how do i merge the two images and make the non different parts transperent

Comment: try to change the colour of the same parts using byte[]. and using a watermark method put it on a white screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create and fill a target `Bitmap`.

Do try to use `LockBits` if performance is too bad. 
Using a library should be even faster.

Here is a quick piece of code; you pass in two `Bitmaps` and the `Color` the differences should be painted in, e.g. `Color.Red` or `Color.Transparent`.

It returns the difference `Bitmap` or null if the `Bitmap Size`s don't match.

```
public Bitmap getDifferencBitmap(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, Color diffColor)
{
    Size s1 = bmp1.Size;
    Size s2 = bmp2.Size;
    if (s1 != s2) return null;

    Bitmap bmp3 = new Bitmap(s1.Width, s1.Height);

    for (int y = 0; y < s1.Height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < s1.Width; x++)
        {
            Color c1 =    bmp1.GetPixel(x, y);
            Color c2 =    bmp2.GetPixel(x, y);
            if (c1 == c2) bmp3.SetPixel(x, y, c1);
            else          bmp3.SetPixel(x, y, diffColor);
        }
    return bmp3;
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(filepath1);
Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(filepath2);
Bitmap bmp3 = getDifferencBitmap(bmp1, bmp2, Color.Transparent);

bmp3.Save(filepath3, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

bmp1.Dispose();
bmp2.Dispose();
bmp3.Dispose();
```

Make sure you dispose of the `Bitmaps` when you are done with them!

Of course you can easily change the logic to make identical parts Transparent and non-identical parts whatever.. I assumed you really wanted to show the differences, though.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411114/c-sharp-copy-bitmaps-pixels-in-the-alpha-channel-on-another-bitmap/24411925#24411925) is a post which contains the code for a LockBits version; you just would need to change the inner loop's code to this:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < s1.Width; x++)
    {
        int index1 = y * bmp1Data.Stride + x * bpp1;
        int index2 = y * bmp2Data.Stride + x * bpp2;
        int index3 = y * bmp3Data.Stride + x * bpp3;
        Color c1, c2;
        if (bpp1 == 4)
                c1 = Color.FromArgb(data1[index1 + 3], data1[index1 + 2], data1[index1 + 1], data1[index1 + 0]);
        else  c1 = Color.FromArgb(255, data1[index1 + 2], data1[index1 + 1], data1[index1 + 0]);
        if (bpp1 == 4)
                c2 = Color.FromArgb(data2[index2 + 3], data2[index2 + 2], data2[index2 + 1], data2[index2 + 0]);
        else  c2 = Color.FromArgb(255, data2[index2 + 2], data2[index2 + 1], data2[index2 + 0]);
        Color putColor = (c1 == c2 ? c1 : diffColor);

        data3[index3 + 0] = putColor.B;
        data3[index3 + 1] = putColor.G;
        data3[index3 + 2] = putColor.R;
        data3[index3 + 3] = putColor.A;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that you can check two image and compare pixel to pixel

```
public void matchimage(System.Drawing.Bitmap img1, System.Drawing.Bitmap img2)
    {
        string img1_ref, img2_ref;
        int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
        bool flag = true;

        if (img1.Width == img2.Width && img1.Height == img2.Height)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < img1.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < img1.Height; j++)
                {
                    img1_ref = img1.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
                    img2_ref = img2.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
                    if (img1_ref != img2_ref)
                    {
                        count2++;
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    count1++;
                }

            }
            if (flag == false)
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, Images are not same , " + count2 + " wrong pixels found");
            else
                MessageBox.Show(" Images are same , " + count1 + " same pixels found and " + count2 + " wrong pixels found");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("can not compare this images");

        img1.Dispose();
        img2.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Bring it up a bit late, but the methods from Bitmap : GetPixel/SetPixel are the slowest ever.

Comment: Yes @PommeDeTerre because above method get all bitmap pixel and compare every pixel I think it will work for small files, if you have large resolution of file you need to find batter solution.

Comment: I'm trying to build a more consistant way using Alea GPU to compare and DirectX or OpenGL to extract front buffer of the graphic device. I may post an answer if i succeed :)