# Image occupies same number of bytes irrespective of color depth

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap

The following picture shows what happens when we convert a 24-bit color image of size 1x2.

[image]

.

The following picture shows what happens when we convert a a 32-bit color image of size 1x2.

[image]

I thought, 24-bit image will occupy 6-bytes. But, both are taking 8-bytes.

As a result, my C# code is failing. Coz, it assumes that a pixel needs `(ColorDepth/8)*Width*Height` number of bytes.

```
    public static int[,] ToInteger(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        BitmapLocker locker = new BitmapLocker(bitmap);

        locker.Lock();

        byte[] data = locker.ImageData;
        int Width = locker.Width;
        int Height = locker.Height;
        int noOfBytesPerPixel = locker.BytesPerPixel;
        int[,] integerImage = new int[Width, Height];
        int byteCounter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
            {
                int integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, byteCounter);

                integerImage[i, j] = integer;

                byteCounter += noOfBytesPerPixel;
            }
        }

        locker.Unlock();

        return integerImage;
    }
```

**So, what is going on really?**

Comment: Maybe its memory alignment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: Look into [stride](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595836/size-of-bitmap-byte-differs-from-bmp-memorystream-size/24595963#24595963)!

Answer (score 1):

**Why are images occupying the same number of bytes ?**

We can't tell for sure since you didn't show how you're acquiring them (maybe they get promoted to 32bpp by default which is the fastest to process, like in [WriteableBitmapEx](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) for instance ?)

**The proper formula to compute bytes per pixel:**

> bytesPerPixel = (bitsPerPixel + 7) / 8

**Here's an example that will convert whatever that is from 8 to 32 bpp to `int`:**

```
private static void DoWork(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    var width = bitmap.Width;
    var height = bitmap.Height;
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var data = bitmap.LockBits(rectangle, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

    var bitsPerPixel = GetBitsPerPixel(bitmap.PixelFormat);
    var bytesPerPixel = (bitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
    var stride = data.Stride;
    var length = stride * data.Height;
    var pixels = new byte[length];
    Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, pixels, 0, length);

    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        var offset = y * stride + x * bytesPerPixel;
        var value = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < bytesPerPixel; i++)
            value |= pixels[offset + i] << i;
    }
    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
}

private static int GetBitsPerPixel(PixelFormat format)
{
    switch (format)
    {
        case PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed:
            return 1;
        case PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555:
            return 2;
        case PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb:
            return 24;
        case PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb:
            return 32;
        default: // TODO
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

(not sure about the usefulness, though)

**Note:** I've 'emulated' what was necessary since I didn't use `BitmapLocker` class as you did.

Comment: what about monochrome and 4-bit images?

Comment: Can you be more precise ?

Comment: this source code can't handle 1-bit monochrome image and 4-bit/16-color images.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/F0uxRKk.png

This is a monochrome image.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/TeTupcN.png   This is a 4-bit(16-color) image.

Comment: You should update your question and clearly explain what you're looking for, because it's unclear for me :) Are you looking for a code that converts any depth to `int` ? etc ...

Comment: There is a perfectly valid `Image.GetPixelFormatSize()` to get the accurate amount of bits for a `PixelFormat`. As for converting an image to 32bpp, I find that a very easy general method is to just make a new 32bpp image object, open its `Graphics`, and simply _paint the other image on it_.