# Image brightness for big images c#

Tags: c#, image, brightness

I use this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33838/Image-Processing-using-C) to add my program the capability to adjust the brightness of the image. This code is ok but it takes time to adjust the brightness(Image file size 1.8mb). When I try the lower quality image it instantly adjusts the image(Image file size 100KB). Is there any efficient way to adjust the brightness of the image.

Comment: you could edit it using a more low level approach. http://www.vcskicks.com/fast-image-processing.php

Comment: You will always have a difference when working on a very small image in comparison to a large one ( 100 kB vs 1.8MB ). So what do you expect from a solution to this question?

Comment: The code seems to use SetPixel on regular Bitmaps. This is a bad idea because it is sooo slow. Instead use a) LockBits or b) a FastBitmap or c) a ColorMatrix! Plenty of examples around here and the web..

Comment: @TaW Ok thanks. Currently looking the lockbits. can you move your comment to answer so I can mark that us answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code seems to use `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` on regular `Bitmaps`. This is a bad idea because it is so slow.

To manipulate a single pixel of a `Bitmap` it must be locked (which Get/SetPixel do behind the scenes) and doing it on a pixel by pixel basis means that for a 1000x1000 sized image a million locking/unlocking operations must be performed. This creates an enormous overhead.

**Method one**

One way to avoid this is to lock the whole bitmap with the [`LockBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx) function. Now we can loop over the pixels and modify them.

Two notes about this method:

- What we now access are the raw bytes of each pixel, that is each channel separately: either BGR or BGRA, depending on the pixel format. This means that the channels are **physically reversed** from the usual RGB/ARGB format of the Color methods.
- To loop over the physical bitmap pixel rows we also need to add some [`stride`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride(v=vs.110).aspx) to each row, which pads the rows to a multiple of 4 bytes. Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595836/size-of-bitmap-byte-differs-from-bmp-memorystream-size/24595963#24595963)

For some examples you may want to browse over [some of these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+lockbits). Note especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792723/adding-or-subtracting-color-from-an-image-in-a-picturebox-using-c-sharp/28799612?s=1|0.1770#28799612) which uses a delegate to allow for flexible operations!

(Note that several of the posts use 2 or even 3 locked bitmaps because they aim at combining images..)

**Method two**

Another way to get around the overhead of locking pixels one by one are ready-made bitmap classes that help by locking themselves as a whole. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701703/c-sharp-faster-alternatives-to-setpixel-and-getpixel-for-bitmaps-for-windows-f/34801225#34801225) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/240428/work-with-bitmap-faster-with-csharp) are examples I didn't try myself.

**Method three**

Finally there is a very elegant method for image manipulation, which is both rather simple and really fast; also professionally crafted for best results: You can set up a [`ColorMatrix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix(v=vs.110).aspx).

It will let you change brightness, gamma, hues and then some. [Here is a very nice introduction](https://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/colormatrix-guide/).

The only drawback is, that is limited to some fixed operations, so you can't create custom filters for other fancy stuff, like [photoshop-type layer modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919663/how-does-photoshop-blend-two-images-together) or others,  especially those that need to process neighbouring pixels e.g. for blurring..

But if all you want is changing brightness, this is what I would recommend!