Blazor Hybrid app and SkiaSharp performance improvements
I am trying to make a simple Maui Blazor Hybrid application that would load a picture, and I would be able to adjust brightness in real time. I managed to do it manually just using simple < img >  and adjusting it accordingly, but it's very slow when using 4k and above pictures. Works fine with FullHD photos. After a bunch of failed attempts, I decided to move to SkiaSharp, because of recommendations. But I am failing to find an example or a concrete answer how to implement it. When I write this piece of code, I get an unexpected unhandled exception
@using SkiaSharp
@using SkiaSharp.Views.Blazor

<SKCanvasView OnPaintSurface="OnPaintSurface" Width="800" Height="600" />

Is it just not feasible ? Or I am missing something ? I saw an old article that it might not be feasible but it's quite old, and only one person answered....
Any advice, how to implement SkiaSharp, or improve performance in other way, would be greatly appreciated.
I am using .Net8, and I can change to any version that would work the best. I am not attached to any particular library or version.
Also from my understanding the only option is to somehow implement GPU support.

Could you please include in the post what .NET version and platform you are using.

@LiqunShen-MSFT I updated it I hope, that helps.

Skiasharp does not work in razor component. You could check my answer.

See my answer to a different question for an explanation of how to use SkiaSharp with Maui Blazor. BOTTOM LINE: SkiaSharp won't be inside the web view; you won't manipulate it via a Razor component; use SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls.SKCanvasView. Starting with SkiaSharp 3.x, SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls.SKGLView will be gpu accelerated.

The unhandled error relates to this GitHub known issue Blazor Maui project using Razor component with SkiaSharp fail #5725. SkiaSharp does not work in mobile blazor as of today and it's a matter of functionality in SkiaSharp and its related Blazor component.
To improve performance, you may also refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031960/image-brightness-for-big-images-c-sharp.

True but might be misunderstood. Can use SkiaSharp in Maui; just not part of a Blazor component. It will be a separate Maui control; not inside the BlazorWebView that displays Blazor content. See link in my comment on question.
