# Merge color and shadow images together

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I am trying to "blend" two transparent images together: one is for color, the second one is for shadow. Here are two images I have:

[image]
[image]

And here is the result I am looking for:

[image]

Ignore the logo on the last one. I was trying to use this code https://softwarebydefault.com/2013/03/10/bitmap-blending/
but it produces this result:
[image]

Can anyone point if I am using correct method? May be I should use some other algorithm to achieve required result?

Comment: In Photoshop terminolgy you have to _multiply_ the two images.

Comment: @TaW, can you get the result with photoshop 'multiply' function? I will search for that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rehshing [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411114/c-sharp-copy-bitmaps-pixels-in-the-alpha-channel-on-another-bitmap/24411925#24411925) `LockBits` code this is the result

[image]

of this function:

```
public Bitmap Multiply(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
{
    Size s1 = bmp1.Size;
    Size s2 = bmp2.Size;
    if (s1 != s2) return null;

    PixelFormat fmt1 = bmp1.PixelFormat;
    PixelFormat fmt2 = bmp2.PixelFormat;

    PixelFormat fmt = new PixelFormat();
    fmt = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
    Bitmap bmp3 = new Bitmap(s1.Width, s1.Height, fmt);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, s1.Width, s1.Height);

    BitmapData bmp1Data = bmp1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, fmt1);
    BitmapData bmp2Data = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, fmt2);
    BitmapData bmp3Data = bmp3.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, fmt);

    byte bpp1 = 4;
    byte bpp2 = 4;
    byte bpp3 = 4;

    if (fmt1 == PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb) bpp1 = 3;
    else if (fmt1 == PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb) bpp1 = 4; else return null;
    if (fmt2 == PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb) bpp2 = 3;
    else if (fmt2 == PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb) bpp2 = 4; else return null;

    int size1 = bmp1Data.Stride * bmp1Data.Height;
    int size2 = bmp2Data.Stride * bmp2Data.Height;
    int size3 = bmp3Data.Stride * bmp3Data.Height;
    byte[] data1 = new byte[size1];
    byte[] data2 = new byte[size2];
    byte[] data3 = new byte[size3];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmp1Data.Scan0, data1, 0, size1);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmp2Data.Scan0, data2, 0, size2);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmp3Data.Scan0, data3, 0, size3);

    for (int y = 0; y < s1.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < s1.Width; x++)
        {
            int index1 = y * bmp1Data.Stride + x * bpp1;
            int index2 = y * bmp2Data.Stride + x * bpp2;
            int index3 = y * bmp3Data.Stride + x * bpp3;
            Color c1, c2;

            if (bpp1 == 4)
                c1 = Color.FromArgb(data1[index1 + 3], data1[index1 + 2], data1[index1 + 1], data1[index1 + 0]);
            else c1 = Color.FromArgb(255, data1[index1 + 2], data1[index1 + 1], data1[index1 + 0]);
            if (bpp2 == 4)
                c2 = Color.FromArgb(data2[index2 + 3], data2[index2 + 2], data2[index2 + 1], data2[index2 + 0]);
            else c2 = Color.FromArgb(255, data2[index2 + 2], data2[index2 + 1], data2[index2 + 0]);

            data3[index3 + 0] = (byte)( c1.B * c2.B / 256);
            data3[index3 + 1] = (byte)( c1.G * c2.G / 256);
            data3[index3 + 2] = (byte)( c1.R * c2.R / 256);
            data3[index3 + 3] = c1.A;
        }
    }

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data3, 0, bmp3Data.Scan0, data3.Length);
    bmp1.UnlockBits(bmp1Data);
    bmp2.UnlockBits(bmp2Data);
    bmp3.UnlockBits(bmp3Data);
    return bmp3;
}
```

Note that the alpha channel is copied from the 1st bitmap.

Instead of 'Multiply' 'ColorBurn' is also a good candidate. [Here](http://photoblogstop.com/photoshop/photoshop-blend-modes-explained) is very nice write-up of the math for the various blending modes.

Update: Using  Anna's algorithm

```
    data3[index3 + 0] = (byte)(c2.B + (c1.B * (255 - c2.B) / 256f));
    data3[index3 + 1] = (byte)(c2.G + (c1.G * (255 - c2.G) / 256f));
    data3[index3 + 2] = (byte)(c2.R + (c1.R * (255 - c2.R) / 256f));
```

results in this lighter image:

[image]

To keep the red colors everywhere and still make the result lighter I would apply a little gamma correction with a [Color Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116706/how-to-repair-dimmed-image-of-book-page/34121073?s=2|0.5054#34121073).

Comment: do you know that you are the MAN?! Thanks so much! That is exactly what I needed, works like a charm.

Comment: Wow, legandary. Just wondering if my algorithm worked BTW. xD

Comment: @Anna: I did try and while nice, the result was color inverted. See my update!

Comment: Oh no xD forgot that RGB gives more light on higher values :P Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @Anna: I have now coded your formula correctly and it looks also nice, no longer inverted, but maybe a little too 'transparent'  for a t-shirt ;-)

Comment: Oh, I was actually thinking about the general idea of lowering the RGBA values of the shade images until white gets red, but as I mistakenly took #000 as white, the whole thing got inverted. Anyway, OffTopic: if you have any expertise in UWP, can you take a look at my latest question? I'm completely doomed, thanks.

Comment: Sorry completely out of my depth there :-(

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for ignoring that blog, I actually read it a bit but had my own algorithm to come up with, you can ignore me as well xD.

It is simple, for each pixel:

1. In the main image (red) find the RGBA values, let's call it `ColorM`.
2. In the shade image, find the RGBA values, let's call it `ColorS`.
3. For each of R, G, B and A values, calculate `((255 - ColorM) * ColorS) / 255`, let's call the final RGBA value `ColorOver`.
4. Calculate `ColorM + ColorOver` and it will give the final image.

Test it if you wanted, seems a bit buggy.

Comment: Thanks Anna, I was just trying to implement A*B/255 but it is not quite what I am looking for. Let me check your formula...