# How can I highlight white blobs in a dark image without for loop?

Tags: c#, image-processing, gdi, colormatrix

I have a task of highlighting UV marks from a dark image (UV marks light up). I have achieved it using a for loop. But I must do it in a very short time. 
I have tried colormatrix, but I didn't see a threshold so that I can assign a value black if the pixel value is less than say, 200 and white above it, while using the class.

How do I detect UV marks from a dark image?

Comment: Try to add some sample input images & also your desired output images.

Comment: For loops are fast. You didn't sow us your code but if it is using `GetPixel`, this __is__ slow. Use `Lockbits`! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407410/how-to-get-difference-between-2-images-and-save-it-to-an-image/24409305?s=22|0.0000#24409305) for an example (using two Bitmaps, you probably only need one)! [Here is another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976620/how-can-i-color-pixels-that-are-not-black-in-bitmap-in-yellow-using-lockbits/25977692#25977692).